# Div height relative to another div on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My function below, loads correctly on initial load and sets the div height to match the height of the video. However when I resize the window the element `#top-content` looses its height.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    var vidHeight = jQuery('video').height();
    jQuery('#top-content').css({
        'height': vidHeight + 'px'
    });
    var vidPicHeight = jQuery('.video-element').height();
    jQuery('#top-content').css({
        'height': vidPicHeight + 'px'
    });
    console.log(vidHeight);
}).trigger('resize');
```

I have a console log running and it the variable `vidHeight`is changing as the window resizes, it is just not updating the style.

Comment: But you are overwriting height style with `vidPicHeight` variable. Is it not mistake ?

Comment: Your code looks good, have you checked if the issue is not related to css or another script?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var vidHeight = jQuery('video').height();
    jQuery('#top-content').css('height', vidHeight);
```